# multiple values in R and store it in a list

Tags: r, console, user-input

I want to take user input from the console.
salary, list of companies and list of jobs.

I am able to take individual values of companies and jobs as character from the console, but how to take multiple values and store it in a variable for further analysis? I need to store and access those values.

Code:

```
     ##############Classs Declaration############
     setClass(Class="User",
             representation(
               salary="numeric",
               company="character",
               jobtitle="character"

             ))
    ###############Function Declaration##########
    myFunction <- function(){ 
      sal <- readline("Salary?")  
      comp <- readline("Company?")
      job <- readline("Job Title?")

      sal <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(sal, ",")))
      comp <- as.character(comp)
      job <- as.character(job)

      return(new("User",
                 salary=sal,
                 company=comp,
                 jobtitle=job

                 ))
    }

    ##########Calling the function########
    aUser = if(interactive()) myFunction()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not clear about the expected output.  I was able to store multiple values using the same function.  For example, when I enter `Salary?25, 32` and `aUser@salary#[1] 25 32`

Comment: the solution you said is working for numeric values  but it is not working for character type values. It shows the entire string.

Comment: You have to `split` that string similar to the one for `sal`

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

A few notes:

(1) use identical instead of `==` inside if statement. `?"=="` or [this post](http://datafireball.com/2014/11/17/r-is-so-dangerous/)

(2) I don't think you can easily run this interactively as a script from the command line. Post as comment if anyone knows how to make this R script as a shell command.

(3) You can either use `dput` or `write` command to store the result to a static file for later use.

```
# result variable is an array used to store user input
# remove result variable from the environment
if(exists("result")){remove(result)}
while(identical(flag_continue <- readline("continue?:"), "y")){
    aUser <- myFunction()
    if(!exists("result")){
      result <- c(aUser)
    } else {
      result <- c(aUser, result)
    }    
}
# now all the user typed info has been stored inside a list called "result"
```

Output:

```
continue?:y
Salary?1
Company?com1
Job Title?job1
continue?:y
Salary?2
Company?com2
Job Title?job2
continue?:n
> str(result)
List of 2
$ :Formal class 'User' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 3 slots
.. ..@ salary  : num 2
.. ..@ company : chr "com2"
.. ..@ jobtitle: chr "job2"
$ :Formal class 'User' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 3 slots
.. ..@ salary  : num 1
.. ..@ company : chr "com1"
.. ..@ jobtitle: chr "job1"
```

Also, you can convert that nested list class ...etc... `result` object into a dataframe:

```
convertUser <- function(result){ 
  data.frame(
    salary = unlist(lapply(result, FUN=function(x){attr(x, "salary")})),
    company = unlist(lapply(result, FUN=function(x){attr(x, "company")})),
    jobtitle = unlist(lapply(result, FUN=function(x){attr(x, "jobtitle")}))
  )
}
df <- convertUser(result)
```

Now `df` looks like this:

```
> convertUser(result)
salary company jobtitle
1      3    com2     job3
2      2    com2     job2
3      1    com1     job1
```